# Javascript variable undefined until break point is placed in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm creating a class for a 3D object. I'm using jQuery for event logging and three.js for WebGL.

My class is defined as:

```
function Obj(filename) {
   this.loadMesh(filename);
};

Obj.prototype.loadMesh = function(filename) {
  var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
  var geo;
  var mesh;
  loader.load(filename, function ( geometry ) {
    geo = geometry;
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.y = -0.25;
    mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.04 );
  });
  this.geometry = geo;
  this.mesh = mesh;
};
```

This class is called from a Scene class:

```
function Sce() {
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 10000);
  this.scene.add(this.camera);
  this.light = new THREE.PointLight();
  this.light.position.set(-256, 256, -256);
  this.scene.add(this.light);
  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  this.obj3d = new Obj('file.ply');
  this.scene.add(this.obj3d.mesh);
};
```

Which is in turn called from the jQuery ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  scene = new Sce();
});
```

But the variables this.geometry and this.mesh are not defined unless I put a breakpoint with Firebug at them.

I think it might be a scope problem, but I haven't been able to fix the error, does someone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Because it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: Also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thanks, it was that. I solved it creating a container object for the geometry in the load call, using THREE.Geometry().